# C++: Problems with having a containing class call a function from a contained class

Tags: c++, oop

I believe this might be an issue of #including or forward declaring, rather than an issue of my syntax, since I'm currently getting errors of "invalid use of incomplete type 'struct MainWindow'", and "forward declaration of 'struct MainWindow' when I attempt to build the following in Qt Creator (Qt 4.7.4):

MYCLASS.H

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

class MainWindow;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(MainWindow * parent);
    void callParentFunction();

private:
    MainWindow *myPointer;
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

MYCLASS.CPP

```
#include "myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(MainWindow *parent) : myPointer(parent)
{
}

void MyClass::callParentFunction()
{
    myPointer->setSpinBoxValue(500);
}
```

MAINWINDOW.H

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>
#include "myClass.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow();
    void setSpinBoxValue(double x);

private:
    QDoubleSpinBox *mySpinBox;
    MyClass *myObject;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MAINWINDOW.CPP

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    mySpinBox = new QDoubleSpinBox;
    setCentralWidget(mySpinBox);

    myObject = new MyClass(this);
    myObject->callParentFunction();
}

void MainWindow::setSpinBoxValue(double x)
{
    mySpinBox->setValue(x);
}
```

I'd appreciate any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `mainwindow.h` in `myclass.cpp` **after** `myclass.h`. In `myclass.cpp` you call a method of the `MyClass` (inside `MyClass::callParentFunction`), but at that point the compiler still only has the forward-declaration of `MainWindow`.

Comment: Damn, 46secs late... I'll delete my post: Yours is better anyway... +1

Comment: D'oh!!! Thank you. At least the code should be helpful for someone else attempting to do this...